# select the max value and other values from three different tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables with the following structure:-

```
CREATE TABLE `contract` (
  `conid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `servName` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `term` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `monthly_charge` double NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `expiry_Date` date NOT NULL,
  `next_PayDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`conid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `servName` (`servName`,`cid`)
) 

CREATE TABLE `servicetype` (
  `sid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `serviceName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sid`)
) 

CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `tid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `conid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amount` double NOT NULL,
  `paidate` date NOT NULL,
  `descr` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tid`)
)
```

What I want to get is the latest transaction for a particular user i.e:-

conid, serviceName, cid, term, monthly_charge, start_date, expiry_Date, next_PayDate,  amount, paidate, descr

And this is the select statement I am using the get to that information:-

```
SELECT c.conid, serviceName, cid, term, monthly_charge, start_date, expiry_Date, next_PayDate, status, amount, paidate, descr
FROM servicetype s 
LEFT JOIN contract c on s.sid = c.servName 
LEFT JOIN transactions t ON c.conid=t.conid
WHERE cid = 4 AND status = 1
```

The statement works but, it is giving me all transactions belonging to cid 4 and all I want to display is only the latest transaction belonging to the said contract it (conid).

Thanking you in advance for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use MySQL's `GROUP BY` to group all of the results by a specific `cid`, and then use a `HAVING` condition to get the `MAX()` transaction:

```
SELECT
    c.conid, serviceName, cid, term, monthly_charge, start_date, expiry_Date, next_PayDate, status, amount, paidate, descr
FROM servicetype s 
    LEFT JOIN contract c on s.sid = c.servName 
    LEFT JOIN transactions t ON c.conid=t.conid
WHERE
    cid = 4 AND status = 1

GROUP BY cid
HAVING t.paidate = MAX(t.paidate)
```

Comment: newFurniturey: Yours was only singular result for the max paidate. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 1):

You can `JOIN` twice on the `transactions` table.  The first join gets the `max()` date for each `conid` and then the second join will return the details of that max transaction:

```
select c.conid,
  s.serviceName,
  c.cid,
  c.term,
  c.monthly_charge,
  c.start_date,
  c.expiry_date,
  c.next_PayDate,
  c.status,
  t2.amount,
  t1.paidate,
  t2.descr
FROM servicetype s 
LEFT JOIN contract c 
  on s.sid = c.servName 
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT max(paidate) paidate, conid
  FROM transactions
  GROUP BY conid
) t1
  ON c.conid=t1.conid
LEFT JOIN transactions t2
  ON t1.paidate = t2.paidate
  AND t1.conid = t2.conid
WHERE c.cid = 4 
  AND c.status = 1
```

Edit, based on your comments the query should be:

```
select c.conid,
  s.serviceName,
  c.cid,
  c.term,
  c.monthly_charge,
  c.start_date,
  c.expiry_date,
  c.next_PayDate,
  c.status,
  t3.amount,
  t3.paidate,
  t3.descr
FROM servicetype s 
LEFT JOIN contract c 
  on s.sid = c.servName
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT max(paidate) paidate, conid, max(tid) tid
  FROM transactions t
  GROUP BY conid
) t1
  on c.conid = t1.conid
LEFT JOIN transactions t3
  on t1.conid = t3.conid
  and t1.paidate = t3.paidate
  and t1.tid = t3.tid
where c.cid = 4
  and c.status = 1
GROUP BY c.conid;
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23555/62)

Comment: Bluefeet: Your statement returns the same result as my initial statement. It shows all transactions for user 4 whereas I am only trying to show all the latest transactions per service.

result can be seen on this image http://i.imgur.com/ui99S.png

Comment: @user1717314 any chance you can create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8fd6) with some sample data?

Comment: @user1717314 please see this fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23555/27 -- I made a slight adjustment and it is returning two records because you have two items for the same `conid` for the same `paidate`, if that happens which one do you want to return?

Comment: the one with the higher tid (transaction id) should be run but, this should also show all other records for cid 4; in otherwords there should be a unique record for every service and the unique record should be the latest. Really appreciate your help

Comment: @user1717314 please see this fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23555/36 -- if it works then I will edit my answer here

Comment: on that fiddle the max(tid) and the amount returned do not correspond. If you look at transactions tid 12 would return 1660 as the amount whereas this fiddle returns the value belonging to tid 11

Comment: @aniga lets try one more time -- check this fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23555/41

Comment: that does it for the correct record but how would I get all the other records (services) belonging to cid 4 now?

Comment: @aniga see this fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23555/62 -- this shows one record for accounting and one for share holder

Comment: That is fantastic, I think this does it. Thanks a million

Comment: @aniga if the answer was helpful, be sure to mark it as accepted it will help future visitors. and you get reputation from accepting.